# VHDL-2008 hierarchical signal access to array

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to access an array via VHDL-2008 hierarchical names. I am able to access the whole array, but when I try to access individual array elements, I get the compilation error:

```
ACOM: Error: COMP96_0015: tb.vhd : (13, 43): ':' expected.
```

Is it possible to access individual array elements? What is the correct syntax?

Here's my code:

**DUT**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity dut is
end entity dut;

architecture rtl of dut is
    type t_data is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal s_data   : t_data(0 to 15)   := (others=>(others=>'1'));
begin
    --don't care
end architecture rtl;
```

**TB**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb is
end entity tb;

architecture sim of tb is    
    signal s_data_0 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
    s_data_0    <=  << signal i_dut.s_data(0) : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) >>;

    i_dut : entity work.dut;
end architecture sim;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message from another simulator explains the problem:

> ## ** Error: external_index.vhd(23): (vcom-1307) External name must denote an entire object, not a slice or indexed name of an object.

Comment: verror tells a wonderful story: **"vcom Message # 1307:
An external name must denote the entire target object.  When forming a slice name or indexed name of an external object, the discrete range or index expression(s) must appear after the closing ">>" which
terminates the external name that denotes that object.
[DOC: IEEE Std 1076-2008 VHDL LRM - 8.7 External names]"**. In this case the prefix (8.1) of an indexed name (8.4) is a name (8.1) which can include an external name (8.7).  Same for the prefix of a slice name (8.5). And this gives answers to both OP questions.

Comment: *Is it possible to access individual array elements?* *YES. What is the correct syntax?* Remove the index from the external pathname, fix the type in the external name (including visibility to declaration of type t_data) and place the index expression `(0)` aftter the >>.